# echoing COM port return garbled but consistent charachters

Tags: command-line, tty, serial-port, minicom

I have a RS323 to usb cable connected to a circuit of max3232 IC Chip, everything was checked to be running on windows.
The Tx and Rx are connected to each other to simulate an echo function.
When sending ASCII charachters using `minicom` the returned character of a box with numbers in it, the returned characters are consistent.

Port config: 8N1 with 9600 baudrate

Comment: So you have done some kind of loopback? Thus, baudrate and other settings should not matter, as they affect both sides. Please give the answer (ascii codes) what you receive for a<space>, for `0`, `3`, `8`, `<` and `?' and a handful of other characters.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ac4BvbQt
it can't be displayed them correctly here, but they are on gedit

Comment: Interesting. 0x61 --> 0x01; 0x76 --> 0x16; 0x3F --> 0x1F; 0x46 --> 0x06 and so on. Obviously the lower 5 bit are correct, upper bits become zero. Like if it was 5N1. Can you reproduce this with a different terminal programm like `screen /dev/ttyS0 9600` (insert correct device file)?